# Why does [[NSError alloc] init]; in Xcode throw an error?

Tags: ios, nserror, alloc

I have the following code in Xcode :

```
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

And it throws following error in the logs

```
[NSError init] called; this results in an invalid NSError instance. It will raise an exception in a future release. Please call errorWithDomain:code:userInfo: or initWithDomain:code:userInfo:. This message shown only once.
```

Maybe, you will tell me that the answer is in the log, but I do not understand how to init NSError.

Comment: Because sendSynchronousRequest will alloc the error by itself. thats why you just give a pointer to the error (*). So the Instanz you created will be never used and is invalid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not allowed to create an `NSError` instance via `-init`; use [`-initWithDomain:code:userInfo:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSError/initWithDomain:code:userInfo:) instead or the constructor method [`+errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSError/errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:).

In your case it's redundant anyway as that method will create it in the case of error.

This is the normal pattern for using it:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                  error:&error];
if (!urlData) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
}

// Successful
```

Comment: You mean nil not nul I suppose,

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are doing. You should initialise an NSError* variable by setting it to nil. You don't even have to do that, the compiler does it for you. Initialising it by creating a new NSError object is nonsense. It's the same nonsense that you often see when beginners write

```
NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
array = ...;
```

In the case of NSError, Cocoa rightfully tells you that creating an NSError object without any error information is nonsense and therefore a bug. But there is not the slightest need to do this. Actually, it would break the line that you missed out where you check if error == nil.

Comment: You are not supposed to check for error with `if (error != nil) { ... }`.  You are supposed to check the return value from the method and then use `error`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it replacing:

```
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc]init];
```

to

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

The log itself states that you should use `errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:` or `initWithDomain:code:userInfo:` in order to resolve this issue.

Use of `-[NSError init]` is not recommended and it can cause exception in future release.

[image: Screenshot for warning]

[image: Screenshot for usage 1]

[image: Screenshot for usage 2]

**Example:**

```
    NSError *errMsg = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"domain" code:1001 userInfo:@{  
                      NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Localised details here" }];
```

Answer (score -1):

**In Swift**

**I Solved this**

```
 let error : NSError? = nil
```

Comment: This will never work: an optional declared with `let` cannot change its value. And anyway, the issue in the question does not apply to Swift, the method signature is different. This answer is wrong and off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code for NSError in Swift

```
let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 101, userInfo: [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "error in download"])
```

and use this error

```
  print("Domain : \(error.domain)")
  print("code : \(error.code)")
  print("Description : \(error.localizedDescription)")
```